# Checking well-definedness of the map $H^q(C;G)\to Hom(H_q(C;G'),G\otimes G')$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have a homomorphism
$$h:H^q(C;G)\to Hom(H_q(C;G'),G\otimes G')$$
given by $(h\{f\})\{\sum c_i\otimes g_i\} =\sum f(c_i)\otimes g'_i$ for $\{f\}\in H^q(C;G)$ and $\{\sum c_i\otimes g'_i\}\in H_q(C;G')$.

To check this map is well-defined I need to check $\sum f(c_i)\otimes g'_i$ is independent of the choice of $f$ in its cohomology class and $\sum c_i\otimes g'_i$ in its homology class.

For the independentness of $f$, let $g\in Hom(C_{q-1},G)$. Then $\delta^{q-1}g = g\partial_q$ so $\sum g\partial_q(c_i)\otimes g_i' = 0$ as $c_i$ is a cycle.

Now suppose $\partial(\sum c_i\otimes g_i') = \sum\partial(c_i)\otimes g_i'=0$. Then need to show $\sum f\partial_q(c_i)\otimes g_i' =0$. But I don't know how to get further. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a slight confusion going on. You do not want to suppose that $\partial(\sum c_i\otimes g_i^{\prime})=0$, this just postulates that $\sum c_i\otimes g_i^{\prime}$ is a cycle (which holds by definition if $\sum c_i\otimes g_i^{\prime}$ is supposed to represent an element of $H_q(C,G^{\prime})$ and not the correct condition otherwise). Instead, we want to show that $h\{f\}$ as defined by you vanishes on boundaries. So let $\sum d_i\otimes h_i^{\prime}\in C_{q+1}\otimes G^{\prime}$ (I'm using different notation just to distinguish this $q+1$-chain from the $q$-chains before), we wish to show $\sum f(\partial_{q+1}(d_i))\otimes h_i^{\prime}=h\{f\}(\sum\partial_{q+1}(d_i)\otimes h_i^{\prime})=h\{f\}(\partial_{q+1}(\sum d_i\otimes h_i^{\prime}))=0$. But $f(\partial_{q+1}(d_i))=(\delta^qf)(d_i)=0$ for all $d_i\in C_{q+1}$ as $\delta^qf=0$ since $f$ is a cocycle.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly confused what to assume. Thanks.